# Getting Firebase child key under random key

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

I want to retrive division and rno from for all key in array and compare those values in array with two other strings. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all children. try below code:

```
        FirebaseDatabase    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String rno = ds.child("rno").getValue().toString();
                    String div = ds.child("division").getValue().toString();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: how to get random key for that child?

Comment: i want to change value of all sub 1-5 ,by checking the division and rno with string stored in other variable. if division and rno are matching then only the values should change.

Comment: ds.getKey() will give you key like "-KYhayyhYqKKia2"

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. But you can play on those who fulfill the requirements of the child and fulfill the conditions.

```
            DatabaseReference roomRef = dbRef.child("Everybody Room List Messages");
            ValueEventListener roomEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dsKey : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dsNick : dsKey.getChildren()) {
                            if (dsNick.child("nick").getValue().toString().equals(Nick)) {
                                dsNick.child("image").getRef().setValue("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            roomRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(roomEventListener);
```

Comment: can you write above code with variables i used..i an not understanding what your code do.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

So, if I understand, you need this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
database.getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String snapDiv = item.child("division").getValue().toString();
            String snapRno = item.child("rno").getValue().toString();

            if(snapDiv.equals(divi) && snapRno.equals(roll)){
                //Here you can do everythings you need because division and rno value are those you are searching.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

I can't understand completly your question.
You need to retrieve for each child his **division** and **rno** value. After that you need to compare them with other variables. But in the session these variables are 2 and fixed or you need to compare with a list of pairs?

After that, assuming that the above question will be clarify, if strings are matches, you need to update the value of sub1, sub2,...,sub5 fields?

Please, give us more informations to understand your situation and give you more support.

Comment: values that i want to compare are fixed and stored in variable name ' divi ' and ' roll ' respectively. i want to compare these 2 variable with  division and rno of each entry.

Comment: @RohanAtale if the updated answer above is correct, show me your other doubts